# x86 debug register : how to break on a specific physical address

Tags: debugging, x86, breakpoints, paging, systems-programming

x86 debug registers (dr0 to dr3) allow to break on a specific address when software attempts to read/write in ([intel doc](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html)). And this configured address must be a linear address.

The problem is that when paging is enabled, the same physical address may be mapped to by several different linear addresses from different task.

So, how to break on access to a specific physical address when we do not know all its possible linear alias addresses?

Comment: The same old way: `int 03h` at the address you want the break ;) It's a one-byte instruction and raises the same exception of debug register. You can save the original byte somewhere (even in a disabled debug register! if the context allows it). I don't know if there is a clever way though.

Comment: Where shall I put the `int 03h`?  It seems to me that `int 03h` allows to break on an instruction address. But here, this instruction (that modifies the content of the memory) is not known.  So, the objective is to break on an access to a specific address in the memory in order to get the instruction that modifies the content stored at this address.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I misread your question. I don't think you can break on R/W but with the debug registers unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you could lock something into physical memory. Then breaking on the mapped linear address will effectively monitor the backing physical address.

Comment: It is a strange scenario, how will you access this physical address? If it's kernel space it will be mapped the same on every process, if it's user-space then why should it be mapped on different processes, otherwise how do you access it?

Comment: I was also wondering; can you be more explicit, @Lycan, please?  what do you mean by "monitor the backing physical address"?

Comment: For example on Linux there's [`mlock`](http://www.nbi.dk/cgi-bin/man2html?2+mlock). Windows has [`VirtualLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx). These will keep your virtual memory in physical memory. _If_ they keep it in the same place in physical memory (not sure they do), then a breakpoint on the virtual address is effectively a breakpoint on the physical address.

Comment: @Mahouk I still don't understand the scenario you asked your original question. Node that DRs will not catch memory accesses that are not passed through the memory unit (like DMA) - so the memory has to be mapped. And if it's special address it'll probably mapped in the kernel space which is common to all processes.

Comment: @HaimCohen, suppose you have a shared memory by two user processes X and Y. For X, this memory may be mapped at address xxx whereas for Y, the same memory is mapped at address yyy (with xxx != yyy). If I configure DR with xxx, it won't catch when process Y accesses it. If I configure DR with yyy, it won't catch when process X accesses it. But the problem is that I cannot know all the possible virtual address mapped to this unique memory address (xxx, yyy, zzz, etc.). hope it is more clear now...

Comment: @Lycan, this scenario is not related to swapping or something like that. I hope my answer to Haim Cohen makes things more clear

Comment: @Mahouk I agree that it's possible but I don't think it can happen in a real OS scenario, are you asking on the theoretical option or do you have a real scenario?

Comment: @Haim Cohen, Why do you think it cannot happen in a real OS? That is the situation I am facing. I am curently working on a small extension to a hypervisor kernel and I got stuck because during execution, there is a weird value written at a specific physical address in the memory (this makes the system crash later). So I am trying to know which process is responsible for this modification.

Comment: @Mahouk, ok, I got the scenario. I thought about using some range register to block writes to the area, but don't think it'll work...

Comment: One feasible way to catch writing on specific physical address , I think , is setting all page tables relates to this physical address to Read only.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the underlying kernel, you can only do that with virtualization extensions.  When you are a guest OS, what you think of as physical addresses are virtual to the next layer down; so it can use the debug registers to achieve the desired effect.

If you are willing to modify the kernel, one avenue is to refuse to map a ‘page of interest’, then redirect all faults on this page to the appropriate debuggers.  It is trickier than I am stating, you may have to emulate/singlestep some code and keep some intricate state.